# Flow and InvocableMethod Simple Question

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, collection, invocable-method, apex-variable

How would I create an array of the values from the `flow` and pass them into the APEX `@InvocableMethod`?

My method is taking in a list of Strings:

```
@InvocableMethod
public static List<String> AutoStartFlowToWebservice(List<String> values) {...}
```

And my flow has 4 values to be passed but they need to be combined into one list in order to pass them to the Apex class. Right now they are all separated. Creating a collection variable doesn't seem right to me because there is no where to add the values to it. Is there another step that I need to do within the flow to add the values to the collection variable?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, this could be easy solution.

I would suggest to gather a String value in a comma delimited way from the flow and then pass it to the Invocable method.

The resultant String will look like this:

```
{!varCRCId} & ',' & {!varCRId}  & ',' & {!varManualStart}  & ',' & {!varProcessStep}
```

So change the signature from `List<String>` to `String`

```
public static List<String> AutoStartFlowToWebservice(String values) {...}
```

And, you know how to split comma delimited String and create a `List<String>` in the invocable method (if needed).

Comment: that could work, good idea!